# How to make a bent arrow connection between parallelepipeds?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have three parallelepipeds. I want to make a nice arrow to connect between them. My expected result is

[image]

By using some related code, I defined three cubes as follows:

```
 \pic [fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=blue!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,0) {annotated cuboid={label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=red!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,4) {annotated cuboid={label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
```

My problem how we can locate the arrow in middle of cube and generates a bent arrow between cube A and C. Could you help me to do it?

My full code is at https://www.overleaf.com/8941463bmfjrnvmzwkx

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \pic [fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=blue!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,0) {annotated cuboid={label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=red!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,4) {annotated cuboid={label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure these are cubes? ;o)

Comment: Yes. Let see it in online link

Comment: I'd call them parallelepipeds…

Comment: Thanks for your word. Actually, I do not know exactly the word name. Just multiple cubes.

Comment: Literally, a cube is one of the Platonic solid. That said, I  know how to do it with pstricks. I do not know TikZ well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to put your cuboids into a node, to get anchor points you can use for start and end points of your arrows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
annotated cuboid ..
% unchanged code
}

\tikzstyle{cubecontainer}=[outer sep = 0pt, inner sep= 0pt]
\tikzstyle{connectarrow}=[-{Triangle[angle=60:0pt 2]},
                          line width= 10pt, shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[cubecontainer] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (b) at (4,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
\node[cubecontainer] (c) at (4,4) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}
                                  {label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

\draw [connectarrow]  (a.east) -- (b.west);
\draw (a.north) edge[out=90,in=-180,connectarrow] (c.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a thighter bending, try to modify the looseness:

```
\draw (a.north) edge[out=90,in=-180,connectarrow,looseness=1.8] (c.west);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So if I have many cubes, it means we need use many node. Is it right?

Comment: @user8264 you could use loops for that. Also have a look at my edit, I simplifed the code a little by use of some macros.

Comment: Could you make the second arrow more bent arrow as my expected

Comment: I saw your edit, It is very nice solution. Just adjust the second arrow more bent way. I will accept it

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Now I added one more cube `d` beside the cube `c`. I want to make a connection between `b` and center bottom south of `d`. I used `\draw (b.east) edge[out=0,in=180,connectarrow,looseness=1.8] (d.south);` but I was fail. It cannot connect with center south of node d. How can I adjust it. You can saw the result at https://www.overleaf.com/8941463bmfjrnvmzwkx

Comment: I guess you want `\draw (b.east) edge[out=0,in=-90,connectarrow,looseness=1.8] (d.south);` play around with the in and out angles!

Comment: perfect! I do not know how you can compute the angle of in and out. could you have some reference link or simple way to obtain the angle?

Comment: @user8264 well 0° is at 3 o'clock, 90 is 12 o'clock, -90 6 o'clock respectively